# Using same data element name within for-each

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

More for reference than actual need: what is the `XPath` syntax to allow me to reference an element in a `xsl:for-each` block when the same element name is used elsewhere?

*Please note, unfortunately this must be a 1.0 solution*

For example, I have the following simple XML, and I want to match up the items with the same `id` value...

```
<data>
  <block1>
    <item><id>1</id><text>Hello</text></item>
    <item><id>2</id><text>World</text></item>
  </block1>
  <block2>
    <item><id>1</id><text>123</text></item>
    <item><id>2</id><text>ABC</text></item>
  </block2>
</data>
```

If I have a `for-each` on the `block1`, how can I reference both the `id` within the `block1` and the `id` within the `block2`?

This will work, but I think it is messy...

```
<xsl:for-each select="//block1/item">
  <xsl:variable name="id" select="id"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="text"/> - <xsl:value-of select="//block2/item[id=$id]/text"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

With the result of...

```
Hello - 123
World - ABC
```

Is there a simplified way of replacing the `$id` in `select="//block2/item[id=$id]/text"` so that it is referring to the `id` element from the `for-each`?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it which you may find clearer, and will probably be faster, is to use keys:

```
<xsl:key name="b2" match="block2/item" use="id"/>
```

then

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('b2', id)/text"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I've never fully got my head around keys and exactly how they work... although your very simple example has made it clearer than I've previously experienced

Comment: Hi freefaller, this may help you, especially the graph: http://www.cranesoftwrights.com/resources/xslkeys/

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct and common as it is.  There's no need to simplify it further; it's a standard idiom recognized and used by those working with XSLT.

Comment: Thanks. Is that because it's the easiest solution, or that there simply is no other way of doing it?

Comment: It's easiest and simplest for a loop in XSLT 1.0.  There are situations where you might replace the variable in the `item[]` predicate with another XPath selector directly, but that'd not be appropriate when there are multiple matches over which you wish to iterate and select as you have here.